# How to upload image > 5 mb to server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, nativescript-vue

I have frontend in nativescript-vue and backend in php-laravel-mysql. I want to upload images > 5mb to server . So , anybody know how to do it??

Comment: are you getting some kind of error , if yes then please put that too in question .

Answer (score 2):

Did you check server restrictions?
In apache.ini file, you can check for:

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size

After edit, you have to restart apache.

Comment: I am using nginx server

Comment: Than check config files on nginx. It seems like server restriction.

Answer (score 0):

It’s common to use a third party service like Amazon AWS S3. https://aws.amazon.com/start-now/

At some point you’ll pay for storage and data transfer. But the free tier goes a long way during prototyping.

If you want to go that route, I found this bit of help: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3952

Note that to get it to work, the comments say install nativescript-nodeify.
And the instructions there give an example of using AWS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-nodeify